# HTML form data using $_POST unable to be captured

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get my form data to be displayed using $_Post when form is submitted.

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="reg_form" onSubmit="return validInfo()" method="POST" action="registration.php">
    <div class="registration_form">
        <table class="reg_form_table">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <br>
                <b>Login Details: </b>
                <br>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="input_email" id="input_email" maxlength="20" size="19" value="Enter Email" onChange="ValidateEmail();"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="email_error"></span>
            </td>  
          </tr>

         
          <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <br>
                    <b>User Details: </b>
                    <br>
                </td>
           </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
                
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="input_first_name" id="input_first_name" maxlength="20" size="19" value="Enter First Name" onChange="ValidateFirstName()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="first_name_error"></span>
                </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="input_last_name" maxlength="16" size="19" value="Enter Last Name" onChange="ValidateLastName()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="last_name_error"></span>
                </td>
          </tr>

            
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="subscription" value="en" checked />
                I want to recieve marketing materials
                
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" id="cancel" value="Cancel"> 
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right">
                <br>
                <input input type="submit"  name="submit_form" id="submit_form" value="Register now!">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is registration.php code:

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
        $input_first_name = $_POST['input_first_name'];
        $input_last_name = $_POST['input_last_name'];
        $input_email = $_POST['input_email'];
        $subscription = $_POST['subscription'];
        $input_password = $_POST['input_password'];
    } ?>


Welcome <?php echo $input_first_name; ?> <br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $input_email; ?>
```

When the submit button on the form is clicked, the form data is not sent, and the first name and email address do not appear. Any idea where I went wrong? Thank you!

Comment: what is `onSubmit="return validInfo()"`. Try ``onSubmit="validInfo()"``. As long as the `validInfo()` function return data, you don't have to tell it to.

Comment: Do you mean that nothing is submitted and the page is never refreshed at all? In that case maybe the JavaScript is preventing it. Hard to say as we can't see it, and we don't know if that's the exact behaviour you mean

Comment: when submit button is clicked, it successful validates the form, and goes to registration.php page. However the $input_first_name and $input_email data is not captured and displayed.

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($_POST);` in the registration.php to see if there is any POST data at all. The form seems ok to me, except for the `<input input`, which shouldn't matter though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like perhaps you copy/pasted the form tag from the Internet.

Try **removing** the onSubmit attribute from your  tag if you are not using any JavaScript (if your HTML code above is your whole file):

```
 onSubmit="return validInfo()"
```

In other words, your new form tag should look like:

```
<form id="reg_form" method="POST" action="registration.php">
```

Comment: The OP should clarify and provide full source when requesting assistance. Without knowing what additional code is on the page, or JavaScript files being referenced which may contain the function definition, the question is incomplete. My answer is based on the question provided and assumes there is no additional code to be reviewed. Also, your link you posted to a comment doesn't show me anything, it just refreshes this page.